# NLog config rule not taking affect

Tags: nlog, elmah, nlog-configuration

I have the following nlog.config file for my project. When I debug locally, it works as expected, that Hangfire messages are being filtered to only show **Warn** and above. However on our staging server (IIS 8.5) nlog seems to ignore the rule and just logs everything (including **Info**) to elmah:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Elmah"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Elmah" name="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" layout="${message}" LogLevelAsType="true"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="Hangfire.*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Even if I remove the `Hangfire.*` rule and change the catchall to `minlevel="Warn"` it still logs **Info** items.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a second nlog.config in your bin folder?

Comment: @Julian no there's definitely only one nlog.config

Answer (score 3):

Think you are running two different versions of NLog.

This will capture all log-events with warning (and above levels):

```
<logger name="Hangfire.*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" final="true" />
```

This means all log-events with info or below will try the next rule:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" />
```

Try this configuration instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Elmah"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Elmah" name="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" layout="${message}" LogLevelAsType="true"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="Hangfire.*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" final="true" />
    <logger name="Hangfire.*" maxLevel="Warn" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="elmahWithLogLevelAsType" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. Also, even when I have the catchall (*) set to 'Warn' I still get info level messages. Also, doesn't 'final' mean "don't process any more rules"? so why would it fall through to the next level?

Comment: @benpage What is the  logger-name (with namespace) for those info-level-messages ? Maybe update the layout to `layout="${logger}|${level}|${message}${exception:format=tostring}"`